# Adding two different controllers to a single blade view in laravel which contains two deifferent forms

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application, I have a view to edit my non-admin users (participants) (via admin dashboard).

In this application, each user can add a pet too.

Once an admin goes to a certain participant's profile admin should be able to edit the participant and also the pet info as well if needed.

For that, I have to use two forms, one to update the user and another to update the pet. But both the forms are in a single view.

I've already created the participant controller (ParticipantController) and tested all the methods are working fine.

For the pets too I created a different model and a controller(PetsController).

But now I'm struggling to connect my pets controller to the participant edit blade.

following is the routing for the relevant scenario in my web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

    Route::resource('/admins/roles','Admin\RoleController');
    Route::resource('/admins/users','Admin\UserController');
    Route::resource('/admins/participants','Admin\ParticipantController');

});
```

I've already created the participant's edit form which works properly and looking for some help to adding the petscontroller to the same blade.

following is my participants edit blade

```
@extends('layouts.admin')


@section('content')

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-9">

            <h2 class="view-title">{{ __('Edit User') }}</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="text-left">

            <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btn-admin" href="{{ route('users.index') }}"> {{ __('Back') }}</a> -->

        </div>        

    </div>

</div>


@if ($message = Session::get('success'))

    <div class="alert alert-success">

    <a class="close" onclick="jQuery('.alert').hide()">×</a>

        <p>{{ $message }}</p>

    </div>

@endif

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12" mt-5>

        @if (count($errors) > 0)

        <div class="alert alert-danger">

            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>

                <ul>

                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)

                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>

                    @endforeach

                </ul>

        </div>

        @endif

    </div>

</div>


{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','route' => ['participants.update', $user->id]]) !!}

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">

    <!-- @if($user->image_id != 'default-avatar.png')
        <button type="submit" name="resetphoto" class="btn btn-danger px-3 mr-5 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    @endif
     -->
   
        @if(empty($user->image_id))     
        <center> <img src="/propics/default-avatar.png" alt="Profile Pic" id="profile_pic_display_settings" class="mb-3"></center>
            </p>
        @else
        <center> <img src="/propics/{{$user->image_id}}" alt="Profile Pic" id="profile_pic_display_settings" class="mb-3"></center>
        @endif 
        
        <center><label for="propic" class="btn btn-default subscribe"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></label></center>
        <input id="propic" type="file" name="image_id" class="form-control">
        <label id="file_name"></label>
        @error('propic')
        <span class="help-block" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror

    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-9 mt-5">

                <div class="form-group row">

                    <div class="col-md-6">   

                        {!! Form::text('first_name', null, array('placeholder' => 'First Name','class' => 'form-control txt_txt')) !!}
                        {!! $errors->first('first_name', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!} 

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">  

                        {!! Form::text('last_name', null, array('placeholder' => 'Last Name','class' => 'form-control txt_txt')) !!}
                        {!! $errors->first('last_name', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 ">

                        {!! Form::text('email', null, array('placeholder' => 'Email','class' => 'form-control txt_txt')) !!}
                        {!! $errors->first('email', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}

                    </div>

                    
                    <div class="col-md-6 ">

                        
                        {!! Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password','class' => 'form-control txt_txt')) !!}
                        {!! $errors->first('password', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 ">

                        {!! Form::password('confirm-password', array('placeholder' => 'Confirm Password','class' => 'form-control txt_txt')) !!}

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        {!! Form::select('roles[]', $roles,$userRole, array('class' => 'form-control','multiple')) !!}
                        {!! $errors->first('roles', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('role_id','null', array('class' => 'form-control txt_none')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('gender','null', array('class' => 'form-control txt_none')) !!}

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 text-right px-0 ">

                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-admin-form-cancel mt-5" href="{{ route('participants.index') }}"> {{ __('Cancel') }}</a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-admin-form-save mt-5">{{ __('Save') }}</button>

                </div>

    </div>

</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}

<div class="row">

    <hr class="black_line">

</div>

{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','route' => ['participants.update', $user->id]]) !!}

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">

    <!-- @if($user->image_id != 'default-avatar.png')
        <button type="submit" name="resetphoto" class="btn btn-danger px-3 mr-5 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    @endif
     -->
   
        @if(empty($user->image_id))     
        <center> <img src="/propics/default-avatar.png" alt="Profile Pic" id="profile_pic_display_settings" class="mb-3"></center>
            </p>
        @else
        <center> <img src="/propics/{{$user->image_id}}" alt="Profile Pic" id="profile_pic_display_settings" class="mb-3"></center>
        @endif 
        
        <center><label for="propic" class="btn btn-default subscribe"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></label></center>
        <input id="propic" type="file" name="image_id" class="form-control">
        <label id="file_name"></label>
        @error('propic')
        <span class="help-block" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror

    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-9 mt-5">

                <div class="form-group row">

                    <div class="col-md-6">   

                        {!! Form::text('first_name', null, array('placeholder' => 'Pet Name','class' => 'form-control txt_txt')) !!}
                        {!! $errors->first('first_name', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!} 

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">  

                        {!! Form::text('pet_age', null, array('placeholder' => 'Pet Age','class' => 'form-control txt_txt')) !!}
                        {!! $errors->first('pet_age', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}

                    </div>

                </div>

                

                

                <div class="col-md-12 text-right px-0 ">

                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-admin-form-cancel mt-5" href="{{ route('participants.index') }}"> {{ __('Cancel') }}</a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-admin-form-save mt-5">{{ __('Save') }}</button>

                </div>

    </div>

</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}


@endsection
```

Comment: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68117681/edit) the profile blade code to your question?

Comment: @shaedrich added

Comment: Oh, I meant the profile view not the profile form because I thought, you had difficulties to find out where to put the link for the edit form of the participant and their pet.